# Why does this strategy code not enter any trade?

Tags: pine-script, long-integer, pine-script-v5, trading, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to write my first strategy code, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong. There don't seem to be any errors in the code, but the code isn't producing any entries. Could you help me understand where I'm going wrong?

```
//@version=5
strategy("calcolo ingresso 4", overlay=true)

VAR1A = (close[1]<open[1] and close>open and close>high[1]) 
plotshape(VAR1A,  title = "VAR1A", location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(23, 159, 180), style=shape.triangleup, text="VAR1A") 

var float my_close = na
if VAR1A
    my_close := high[0]

var float my_open = na
if VAR1A
    my_open := low[1]

var float entry_level = (my_close-((my_close - my_open)/2))


//VERIFICA CONDIZIONI INGRESSO LONG
long_condition = false
first_cross_index = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(close, entry_level), bar_index, 0)
last_cross_index = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(close, entry_level), bar_index, 4)
if last_cross_index > first_cross_index
    long_condition := true

// Inserisci l'ordine di ingresso long
if long_condition and VAR1A
    strategy.entry("buy",strategy.long,qty=5000)

// Chiudi l'operazione long se il prezzo chiude sotto entry_level
close_condition = false
close_cross_index = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossunder(close, entry_level), bar_index, 0)
if strategy.position_size > 0 and close_cross_index > 0 and close[close_cross_index] >    entry_level
    close_condition := true

if strategy.position_size > 0 and close_condition
    strategy.close("buy")
```

From the code, I expect it to simply simulate a long entry when the VAR1A condition is met and the price reaches the price level exactly halfway between the high value of the current candle and the low value of the previous candle that triggered the VAR1A condition. It can attempt the entry for the next 4 candles.

Comment: I think your code is fine. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: It is not an error. it is a warning. just ignore her

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I would ignore it, but the problem is that the strategy code does not produce any entries. Yet the condition I set is not a stringent one... I really don't understand how to proceed...any ideas? Maybe I'm making a stupid logic error, but I can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 0):

Your long_condition will never be true because your last_cross_index will always be <= to first_cross_index.

Here is the visual result, with the last_cross_index label above the price and the  first_cross_index below the price :
[image]
You can control it with this code :

```
//@version=5
strategy("calcolo ingresso 4", overlay=true)

VAR1A = (close[1]<open[1] and close>open and close>high[1]) 
plotshape(VAR1A,  title = "VAR1A", location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(23, 159, 180), style=shape.triangleup, text="VAR1A") 

my_close = high[0]
my_open = low[1]

entry_level = (my_close-((my_close - my_open)/2))

//VERIFICA CONDIZIONI INGRESSO LONG
long_condition = false
first_cross_index = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(close, entry_level), bar_index, 0)
last_cross_index = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(close, entry_level), bar_index, 4)

if VAR1A
    label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(last_cross_index))
    label.new(bar_index, close, str.tostring(first_cross_index), yloc = yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_up)

if last_cross_index > first_cross_index
    long_condition := true
```

I think your error comes from this definition :

```
last_cross_index = ta.valuewhen(ta.crossover(close, entry_level), bar_index, 4)
```

The 4 number is for the occurence number, not the number of bars.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you say that close>high[1] is never true. I see many VAR1A conditions being met on the chart, so it means that this condition is often met. Maybe I misunderstood, can you explain it better... thank you very much for your response.

Comment: @SaLa I update my answer, I hope it is more clear.

Comment: WOW! YOUR SOLUTION LOOKS PERFECT. I WILL TEST IT ON A CHART IN THE COMING DAYS AND UPDATE YOU. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!!!!